# I'm currently trying to use OpenCV, but I can't build cargo because this error appears

Tags: opencv, rust-cargo

The content is the same as the title, I am trying to use OpenCV, and if I put opencv = "0.86.1" in cargo.toml, it outputs the following content and I cannot use core functions such as videoio.

error: failed to run custom build command for `clang-sys v1.6.1`

OS: Window 11
IDE: RustRover Preview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRtBB.png)

i added  `clang-sys = "1.6.1"` but it was failed to use

another way was tried to use opencv at an other pc
but its output was same